# Sleeping connections in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems

I'm running the following piece of code to calculate DAU (daily active users) for our app:

```
        EM.run do
            db = EventMachine::Synchrony::ConnectionPool.new(size: numDays) do
            Mysql2::EM::Client.new(
                :host => config[:server],
                :username => config[:user],
                :password => config[:pwd],
                :database => config[:db_name],
                :connect_timeout => 60,
                :cache_rows => false
                )
            end
            slice.to_a.each do
                |day|
                defer = db.aquery("BIG QUERY HERE")

                defer.callback do |obj|
                    puts "#{day} inserted into database"
                    a += 1
                    EM.stop unless a < numDays
                end
            end
        end

start = Time.now
Date.parse(config[:from]).upto(Date.parse(config[:to])).each_slice(config[:slice]) do
    |slice|
    em_dau(config,slice)
    puts "Total time elapsed: #{Time.now-start}"
end
```

What this does is take, say, a year's worth of user data, and slices it up into N-sized chunks, and does the query asynchronously for each of those days, returns to the loop and sends another N-chunk, repeating the process until the full data set is covered. The "problem" (in quotes because I'm not sure it's really a problem) is that while the script is running, it seems that every connection that is made by the client remains in a "sleep" state until the entire script is done running. I assumed that the ConnectionPool was managing the db connections, but now I'm thinking I need to do some explicit management. The problem is I don't actually know how to close the connections within the event loop. Any ideas/advice is welcome. Thanks.